# PHP - Select dropdown and display data on text boxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

i will make this clear. So I just want to display all my data in my text boxes when I select an option or value in my Select Dropdown but I have no clue how to do it. it seems like there's nothing being display after I select a value on select dropdown thanks!

here is what my database looks like

[image]

also i am passing the amount on the selectbox so when i click for example 500 then the textboxes will be filled with its value like `pin` , `code` and other fields inside the table

here is what my page looks like

[image]

```
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="row  col-md-4">

            <?php 

            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
            $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'qrproject');
            ?>


              <label>Amount</label>

              <select class="form-control validate" name="id">
                <?php 
                  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT amount FROM scratch_cards GROUP BY `amount`");
                  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                  echo "<option value=\"amnt1\">" . $row['amount'] . "</option>";
                  }
                ?>
              </select>
               <br>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-warning" name="search" value="Search Data"></input><br>


            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['search']))
            {
              $id = $_POST['id'];

              $query = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE amount='$id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
              $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

              if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
              {
                ?>
                <form action="" method="POST">

                <input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $row['code'] ?>" class="form-control validate" id="mapo">

                   <input type="text" name="pin" value="<?php echo $row['pin'] ?>" class="form-control validate" id="mact">

                   <input type="text" name="txtstatus" value="<?php echo $row['status'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="soluong">



                <input type="date" name="card_expiration" value="<?php echo $row['card_expiration'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="cardex">


                  <input type="number" name="card_validity" value="<?php echo $row['card_validity'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="cardval">

                  <input type="hidden" name="success" class="validate form-control" id="success" value="SUCCESS">

                </form>
                <?php 
              }
            }
             ?>   
        </form>
```

Comment: We don't know if your connection works, we don't know what you database table data looks like.  We don't know what you are passing as `id`.  We don't know if there is a mysql error.  We cannot help because we don't have enough of the story.  **Off-topic: Why isn't my code working**  (and I don't recommend nested form tags)

Comment: @mickmackusa hey sir, im sorry for the inconvenience, i rushed the question so please take a look how i need to detailed the program thanks i edited the code above i added image and details

Comment: @mickmackusa i edited the code above sir please  it is now detailed pls take a look thanks

Comment: @mickmackusa If you also have questions please feel free to ask me thanks

Comment: Here is your problem `value=\"amnt1\"`

Answer (score 0):

No matter what is clicked. `value=\"amnt1\"` will be passing `amnt1` with the submitted data.

You should remove that attribute and just use the text value.

You would have discovered this issue yourself, if you would have simply echoed out `$id`.  Basic diagnostics should be done before posting a question.